# Multiple outputs of a script to a rate

Tags: linux, bash, sh

While doing system administration I often write one-liners to get the status of a process, or some value like used disk-space, number of files processed or seconds left (for example replication). I use tools like `watch` or echo in a loop with `date` to assess the status in real-time.

Often I know the outcome of the value I'm watching: it will go up to a defined number, or zero. To calculate the expected time it will be done (some processes take hours) I would put some timestamps and values in a spreadsheet, calculate some rates of increment or decrement of the value between the timestamps, and average the rate and extrapolate to estimate the expected end-time of the process.

I'm looking for a way to automate this like [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) does this for a pipe. I would expect it to work something like this:

```
$ rate --expected-value=0 --interval=10 "mysql -e 'show slave status' -E | grep Seconds_Behind_Master | awk '{print $2}'"
Fri May 31 10:31:48 CEST 2019 | value: 52952
Fri May 31 10:31:58 CEST 2019 | value: 52918 | rate: 3.4/s | ETA: 10:57:27
Fri May 31 10:32:08 CEST 2019 | value: 52886 | rate: 3.2/s | ETA: 10:58:29
```

or for another example:

```
$ rate --unit byte --interval=1 "stat / -f -t | awk '{print $9}'"
Fri May 31 10:58:03 CEST 2019 | value: 11908091
Fri May 31 10:58:04 CEST 2019 | value: 11829190 | rate: 78900 bytes/s
```

These are examples of course, and the fictive `rate` utility does not exist. I could build it myself but I wonder if there is an existing utility (which I have not found yet) that can do this, maybe a library, or a simple one-liner that would do something similar.

Comment: There is [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv). There is [watch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html). Once you get down to writing such thing you discover, that there are too many cases to handle. Really writing a simple `while sleep 1; do stat / -f -t | awk '{print $9}'; done | { read old; while read new; do echo "$(date) | value: $new | rate: $(new - old)"; old=$new; done; }` is just simpler to customize then using a predefined script.

Comment: @KamilCuk `pv` does exist and covers a lot of features: eta's, progress, and rates, but just for bytes in pipes. This is a different use-case and I'm trying to find possible different solutions before I start developing a similar tool. And as i'm really used working with `pv` it takes no time just include it in my one-liner and see whats going on. This is a feature I miss in my toolbox and have no wish for duplicating the same logic every time I need it, probably the same reason `pv` is developed in the first place.